# Completeness on the tangent bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, finsler-geometry

I was wondering if geodesics are defined for all time on compact Finsler manifolds, or more generally, for any spray on a compact manifold (where by geodesics, I simply mean the integral curves of the spray).

I thought perhaps that the homogeneity condition of a spray would mean that the "size" of vectors couldn't grow too quickly along integral curves. To give a meaning to "size," I thought it would be useful to endow $TM$ with a complete metric, and the natural choice seemed to be the Sasaki metric. But then I realized, I didn't actually know if compactness of $M$ guarantees that the Sasaki metric is complete (I now know that it is). So I ask the following three sub-questions:

1. If $(M,g)$ is complete, is the Sasaki metric on $TM$ necessarily complete?
2. If $M$ is compact, is every spray on $M$ a complete vector field on $TM$?
3. If $M$ is compact and Finsler, do geodesics on $M$ exist for all time?

Comment: Regarding (3). Yes, they do. Consider the geodesic flow as a Hamiltonian system on the cotangent bundle, the energy levels, which are invariant under local flow, are compact and so the geodesic exist for all time.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva Thanks, that's very helpful! My main motivation to learn about some basic Finsler stuff is so that I can read your "dual girth" paper :) But I'm doing background reading first, and I thought it'd also be useful to learn a few other things that I had skipped along the way.

Comment: My dual girth paper has very little Finsler geometry. If you want background for it, it is best to take up Arnold and Givental's really nice survey on symplectic geometry in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-06791-8_1

Comment: While you are at it check out Dmitry Faifman's paper: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-92/issue-2/An-extension-of-Sch%C3%A4ffers-dual-girth-conjecture-to-Grassmannians/10.4310/jdg/1352297806.full

Comment: Both papers use the same background and  make a nice pair, if I say so myself.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations. I was indeed planning to read Faifman's paper after yours. I think that my symplectic/contact background is reasonably good, with the exception of a gaping hole around the Lagrangian formulation, Legendre transformation, etc. Since I recently got interested in some questions about normed spaces/planes, I'm just now trying to write some notes for myself, to simultaneously fill in this hole, start getting an idea of some basic convex/Finsler stuff, and understand your fascinating paper. Hence the questions that may not seem directly relevant to your work.

Comment: For a quick review of all of those things you can go to the survey https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187457410680004X  you can also find the pdf by googling if you don't have access.

Comment: Think of Lorentzian metrics. Sprays on compact manifolds don't have to be complete.

Comment: Check out http://www.numdam.org/article/TSG_1994-1995__13__37_0.pdf

Comment: Wonderful, thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These answers are primarily due to Juan Carlos Álvarez-Paiva's comments. I'm just recounting them:

1. If $(M,g)$ is a complete, then $TM$ is also complete under the Sasaki metric, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116727/completeness-of-the-tangent-bundle-of-riemannian-manifold/4156094#4156094).
2. Not every spray over a compact manifold is complete. Álvarez-Paiva linked [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/TSG_1994-1995__13__37_0.pdf), which gives (as part of a more detailed study) an example of a Lorentzian metric on a 2-torus, where geodesics are not defined for all time. The idea is that a closed geodesic $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ may increase in speed: $$\gamma(1)=\gamma(0)\quad\text{and}\quad\lambda\cdot \gamma'(1)=\gamma'(0)\quad\text{with}\quad\lambda<1.$$ Then $\gamma$ extends to go around infinitely many times and on the $n^\text{th}$ time around, the initial speed is $\lambda^{1-n}\gamma'(0)$ and the orbit takes time $\lambda^{n-1}$. Hence, the first $n$ times around takes time $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\lambda^{k}=\frac{1-\lambda^{n}}{1-\lambda}.$$ As $n\rightarrow \infty$, this time converges to a finite number $\frac{1}{1-\lambda}$, which is the furthest that $\gamma$ extends.
3. Again pointed out by Álvarez-Paiva: on a compact Finsler manifold, the sphere bundles are compact and the geodesic spray is tangent to these sphere bundles. Therefore, in this case, geodesic spray is complete!